# How to reserve a dd into a register, so I can yank it immediately even after a couple more dd's in between

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste

`dd` puts the text I want to yank, in some register.
Before a yank, a couple more `dd`'s, now the first `dd` register has changed.
How do I yank so that it's the first `dd` I want. I can't keep track of registers in between.

Comment: Choose a named register to yank into, then paste from that. For example `"ayy` then delete something, move, and press `"ap`.

Comment: It's awkward to press `"` can I reduce it to like `-yy` `-p`

Comment: The last yanked text is accessible from the `"0` register (see `:help "0`). So, instead of `p`, use `"0p`.

Comment: I tried that, but sometimes when I delete `"0` register replaced by the deleted text so they move. So maybe I want put the `yy`'s into `"0` to `"3` and other yanks from deletions put to `"4 .. "9`

Comment: That's strange. Deleted lines of text should go to the `"1` register, not `"0`. Anyway, if `"0` does not work for you, I recommend either (1) deleting to null register, as in `yy`, `"_d`, `p`, or (2) yanking to a specific register, as per Heptite's comment.

Comment: Oh, are you using any yank-related plugins by any chance? if so, it would be good to add that to your question

Comment: You probably want to read [`:h quote_`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quote_) as husB said the black hole register is a solution to your issue. A great plugin related to this topic is [vim-subversive](https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-subversive) it might help you improving your workflow by providing commands which don't affect your registers.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. I can understand it better now. However, I am still confused by the word "yank" in the question. In vim, "yank" means "copy". Did you mean to use "cut" instead?

Comment: I mean paste when I say 'yank', like in emacs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allow me to rephrase your question. This is to make sure that I understand it fully:

1. You press `dd` to cut some text that you want to paste at a later point in time.
2. You see another line that you wish to remove, and press `dd` to remove it. You may need to do this for multiple lines.
3. Now, you wish to use `p` to paste the text content in step 1.
   However, the content in step 2 is pasted.

---

The solution is to use registers. These are triggered with the `"` key. (If it is difficult to press, we can use a mapping.)

The problem is that `dd` actually does a "cut", instead of "removing" text. That is, in step 2, `dd` actually stores the text, instead of removing it.

We can resolve this is two ways, choose one or the other:

- First, in step 2, use `"_dd` to actually remove the text (cut to null register, or cut to nowhere). This method is preferred if there are few lines to remove.
- Otherwise, in step 1, save the text to some register (*e.g.*, `"rdd`) and paste that register in step 3
  (*e.g.*, `"rp`). This method is preferred if there are many lines to remove in step 2.

We have to make a change either in step 1, or in step 2. This is because we cannot use the same mapping `dd` to both "cut" and "remove" text.

---

If `"` is too hard to press, we can use a mapping. For example, we can use

```
nnoremap - "
```

to replace the `"` key with `-`. Then, using the second solution, we can do

1. `-rdd`
2. `dd`
3. `-rp`